# looking for a book from 30 to 40 years ago about humans recovering lost psychic abilities

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I remember quite a bit of it but not the title or author. Humans were visited aeons ago by a race that went around suppressing psychic development of young species as they were unable to develop these themselves. In modern times another race sends a weapon as a precursor to invasion but the weapon unlocks the humans' psychic abilities and people suddenly are able to alter reality at will, the main character uses the trigger word Aufmachen to stop himself accidentally affecting things.

Comment: Remember to add **everything** that may be of use, such as what the cover looked like, etc.

Comment: Why would the character pick a German word...was he German, was the book not in English?

Comment: @Paulie_D from what i remember he had some knowledge of German and chose a word in a foreign language to avoid accidental triggering.

Answer (score 5):

*[Blindfold from the Stars](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/19218785-blindfold-from-the-stars)* by Philip E.High

> The conquest of a galaxy is relatively easy providing the aggressor has the necessary technology and, more important, a safe method of overcoming possible opposition without bleeding to death in the process. The Asdrake employed mutated micro-organisms which directly attacked the brain of the planet's intelligent life - they liked this method. They could fight if they had to but were inherently lazy. This method had worked successfully on twenty-two occasions - why should it fail on planet 5/6/9. Sector 88. Sun System 46. "Tseudec" (Native name: "Earth").
>
> Casualties from the epidemic were astronomical yet, in complete paradox, failed to kill a single human being - the side effects took care of that. And those side effects were beyond even the Asdrake's imagination. The survivors on Earth found undreamed complications in rebuilding the world with the use of their new psychic powers - and perhaps more important, were they new powers at all, and if not who had removed them thousands of years ago?"

Comment: wow thanks, i think that's it. I'll have to read it but the synopsis sounds right.

Comment: It looks like you have created two accounts. Do you need help in how to merge them?

Comment: yeah, i wondered why i couldn't mark the answer. must be because i used the emailed link on 2 PCs

Comment: @Ephemeron You can find instructions [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) on how to merge your two accounts. Once you've done that, you'll be able to accept this answer, thus marking the question as solved and giving an extra thank-you to the answerer.